# Yii unload bootstrap plugin on ajax request

Tags: php, ajax, yii

i installed this extension http://www.cniska.net/yii-bootstrap/ , is possible  when i make an ajax request to unload from  `'preload'=>array('bootstrap','log'),` :  bootstrap ,i don't need
to use bootstrap on ajax  request , how to avoid that

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/tamada/assets/97e8be51/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
Content updated in AJAX<script type="text/javascript" src="/tamada/assets/cb84ef9f/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/tamada/assets/97e8be51/js/bootstrap-button.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/tamada/assets/97e8be51/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/tamada/assets/97e8be51/js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
jQuery('a[rel="tooltip"]').tooltip();
jQuery('a[rel="popover"]').popover();
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

Thank You A LOT , sorry for my english

Comment: that's an awesome widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can selectively load it in your `config/main.php`.

This might not be the best PHP but it should work. Basically, when loading the config, check whether the request is an AJAX request or not using `Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest`.

Add to top of `config/main.php`:

```
<?php

// Load it by default
$preload = array('bootstrap');

// Don't load it for AJAX requests
if (Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest) {
    $preload = array();
}
```

Then pull in the module (either toggled on or off) using `array_merge`:

```
// preloading 'log' component (with selective bootstrap component)
'preload'=>array_merge(array('log'), $preload),
```

Now when you do an AJAX request to your application the bootstrap module should not be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Please, read: [Yii + AJAX = Duplicate ClientScripts](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/34996-yii-ajax-duplicate-clientscripts/page__p__168372#entry168372).